# How to use deviceiocontrol function properly

Tags: c, winapi

This is my code:

Code:

```
HANDLE HandelUsb= CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\G:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (HandelUsb == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Terminal failure: Unable to open usb ERROR CODE:0x%x\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}

DISK_GEOMETRY d = { 0 };
DWORD dwReturned = 0;

int gs =DeviceIoControl(HandelUsb, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, NULL, 0, &d, sizeof(DISK_GEOMETRY),&dwReturned, NULL);
printf("%d\n", gs);

if (d.MediaType == RemovableMedia)
{
    DWORD dwReturned2 = 0;
    MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA data={ 0 };
    if (DeviceIoControl(HandelUsb, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER, NULL, 0, &data,sizeof(MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA), &dwReturned2, NULL)) {
            printf("SerialNumberLength %d\nResult %d\nReserved[2] %s\nSerialNumberData[1] %s ", data.SerialNumberLength, data.Result, data.Reserved, data.SerialNumberData);
    }
    else {
            printf("faild to get serial number ERROR CODE:0x%x\n", GetLastError());

    }
}

CloseHandle(HandelUsb);
return 0;
```

Everything works well except for the function
Code:

```
DeviceIoControl(HandelUsb, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER, NULL, 0, &data,sizeof(MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA), &dwReturned2, NULL)
```

It always fails (returns a value of 0), GetLastError returns the value 0X1 (problem function).

Maybe someone here can show me what I'm missing here?

Following the comment of @IInspectable ,i changed the code to it:

```
    //volume handle to device handle
VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS volumeToDevice = { 0 };
DWORD Returned = 0;
DeviceIoControl(HandelToUsb,IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS,NULL,0,&volumeToDevice,sizeof(VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS),&Returned,NULL);


WCHAR volume[150] ;
swprintf_s(volume, L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive%d", volumeToDevice.Extents[0].DiskNumber);
wprintf(L"%s\n", volume);

//handle to phisicalDrive
HANDLE HandelUsb = CreateFile(volume, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ |FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
DWORD dwReturned2 = 0;
    MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA data={ 0 };
    if (DeviceIoControl(HandelUsb, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER, NULL, 0, &data,sizeof(MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA), &dwReturned2, NULL)) {
            printf("SerialNumberLength %d\nResult %d\nReserved[2] %s\nSerialNumberData[1] %s ", data.SerialNumberLength, data.Result, data.Reserved, data.SerialNumberData);
    }
    else {
            printf("faild to get serial number ERROR CODE:0x%x\n", GetLastError());

    }
```

I still get a failure 0X1 on function

```
 DeviceIoControl (Handel Usb, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER, NULL, 0, & data, sizeof (MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA), & dwReturned2, NULL)
```

- I ran Windus 7
- i tried to Change the permissions function CreateFile (Add GENERIC_EXECUTE , replace to GENERIC_ALL add FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL ), play with the parameters of the DeviceIoControl.

Comment: You are opening the disk device in your call to `CreateFile`. This is **not** the USB device.

Comment: the createFile support opening disk devices like usb, and i checked in my code that this device is usb (if (d.MediaType == RemovableMedia)) , the problem start only in IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER

Comment: Correction: You are opening a disk **volume**, not the USB device. From [DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216.aspx): *"To retrieve a handle to the device, you must call the [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) function with either the name of a device or the name of the driver associated with a device."* You aren't providing a device name, but rather a volume.

Comment: I know this but look hear [from createFile]:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx   "When opening a volume or removable media drive (for example, a floppy disk drive or flash memory thumb drive), the lpFileName string should be the following form: "\\.\X:". "

Comment: `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER` retrieves the serial number of a USB device. To use it, you need to pass a handle to a **device** to the `DeviceIoControl` function. You are passing a handle to a **volume**. A volume is not a device.

Comment: thank you @IInspectable, i changed the code (and edit the post ), unfortunately the problem still remains

Comment: Are you sure that you opened the device? You should check if `CreateFile` was successful.

Comment: I'm sure and i check it on code (i didn't upload the check code to save space)

Comment: You're still opening a disk device, not the USB device.  I think you're at least on the same device stack now, but I'm not sure whether the higher-level drivers will pass the request all the way down to the actual storage device.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/hardware/ff552547(v=vs.85).aspx ; I *think* `PhysicalDriveN` is "Logical Unit FDO" whereas your request probably needs to be handled by `usbstor.sys` and *may* need to be pointed at a specific device object.  (I may be completely wrong.)

Comment: (WinObj (available from the MS web site) might be useful in experimenting to find which device objects accept that control code.)

Comment: Oh, and there's another problem with the code: the MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER_DATA structure has a variable-length array at the end, so you need to allocate extra space for the members of this array.  Try using a nice big character buffer to start with, presumably 4096 bytes would be plenty.